# A proper subspace of a normed vector space has empty interior clarification

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

So every proper subspace of a normed vector space has empty interior. I'm not asking for the proof, my problem is that this seems to me very strange. 
So if I have a normed vector space, in any proper subspace I can't take any ball inside the subspace?

For example suppose we work on a set with finite measure, $[a,b]$ for example. Let's take $L^{P}$ spaces over $[a,b]$. We know that now $L^{\infty}$ is included in $L^{1}$. So $L^{\infty}$ is a proper subspace of $L^{1}$. Now this means that $L^{\infty}$ is nowhere dense?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that at all. Saying $L^\infty$ is nowhere dense says that the closure $\overline{L^\infty}$ has empty interior, which is much stronger than saying $L^\infty$ has empty interior.

Comment: Proper subspaces are like lines and planes through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$. They don't contain any open balls of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @mechanodroid And hence proper subspaces have empty interior. The OP already knows that - what does this have to do with the question of whether $L^\infty$ is nowhere dense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this means is that $L^\infty$, as a subset of $L^1$, has empty interior (since $L^\infty$ is a *proper* subspace of $L^1$), as you have stated.

But $L^\infty$ is not nowhere dense in $L^1$.  In fact, $L^\infty$ is dense in $L^1$. This is because any $L^1$ function can be approximated by simple functions, which are in $L^\infty$.  Thus the closure of $L^\infty$ is $L^1$, which certianly has nonempty interior in $L^1$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So inside $L^{\infty}$ I can't take any ball?

Comment: What you can do (and it may be useful to do) is take $B\cap L^\infty$ for any ball $B$ in $L^1$.  But this will never be all of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

In the infinite-dimensional case, subspaces are closed by definition. $L^\infty$ is not closed in $L^1$ (its closure is all of $L^1$), so it is not an example of proper subspace.

$L^\infty$ is dense in $L^1$ (even compactly supported functions are). Of course ir is not nowhere dense, its closure is  $L^1$!

And yes, as a subset, $L^\infty$ has empty interior.

Comment: Subspaces are only closed by definition if you define them to be closed, which is certainly not standard.

Comment: For the theorem stated about subspace not having interior, the term subspace has to to be defined as closed subspace. I think it is pretty common to assume closedness (for ex. In the well known textbook by Fomin and Kolmogorov)

Comment: @GReyes It seems however a lot of times we would want to discuss dense subspaces of say $L^p$, as you said above, but this would be meaningless terminology if we assumed subspaces were closed by default.

Comment: @GReyes: No, it doesn't have to be. I don't even see how it would help. (The converse is true, though: you can certainly show that having nonempty interior implies being closed (in fact, clopen) --- this is true for any subgroup of a topological group. Of course this is vacuous for vector subspaces.)

Comment: @GReyes Any proper subspace (closed or otherwise) has empty interior.  Nowhere in the proof is closedness needed.

Comment: @tomasz I absolutely agree with both, the fact is true about any vector subspace. I do not think we disagree about facts, but about terminology. I would call $L^\infty$ a  vector subspace of $L^1$.If we are looking at two structures (vector space+ topology) I think it makes sense to call something a subspace if it is closed both as a vector space and topologically. Maybe we should make the distinction between a vector subspace and a "topological subspace", but again here the terminology would be weird because we use that name for any subset of a topological space with inherited topology...

Comment: @GReyes: the terminology is a matter of convention, which is usually chosen according to what is more convenient at the time; both are used, so neither is standard. What I objected to was you claiming that the theorem is only true as stated under your convention, which is not true.

Comment: @tomasz  You are absolutely right. I meant to say that the example (given my terminology) was not a good example, but ended up saying that the fact was not true, which was completely wrong.